# GRASS and SAGA function not working with QGIS 2.18.12

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, windows-7

I was using QGIS 2.18.7 version where SAGA and GRASS was working fine. On updating to 2.18.10 and now 2.18.12, both SAGA and GRASS has stopped functioning. 
QGIS is installed on win 7 64 bit system.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Now the current version is 2.18.14. Try to install the latest version and make sure you have administration privilege during installation.

Comment: but are you sure in the latest version it will work as for me it was working fine until 2.18.7. It stopped working after that.

Comment: Could you please update your answer addressing the history you mentioned in the comments and how did you install QGIS? Is it using standalone installer or using QSGeo4W? This will limit the time of guessing  what you have done?

Comment: I was using 2.18.7 which was working fine along with GRASS and SAGA. On updating the software to 2.18.10 and now 2.18.12, GRASS and SAGA has stopped working. 
Installed using QSGeo4W.

Comment: Please update your question using the edit button under your question.

Comment: I guess you want to use GRASS and SAGA within the processing toolbox. Make sure you have no processing modules in your `.qgis2` folder. Processing was moved to the core plugins some time ago, but old versions in the mentioned folder may still interfere.

Comment: Hi, which version of saga did you install? I had problems as well, but it turns out I needed to select the ltr version of saga in the osgeo4w installer

Answer (score 1):

*From @AndreJ comment, a useful tip & insight knowledge :*

> "Make sure you have no processing modules in your .qgis2 folder.
>   Processing was moved to the core plugins some time ago, but old
>   versions in the mentioned folder may still interfere."

Answer (score 1):

SAGA has been updated to the version 2.3.2 and some tools for example saga:majorityfilter have 1 more parameter and do not work with the old configuration.

Comment: Hi All,
The issue has been solved. Uninstalled all the QGIS components from the system and installed 2.18.14 once again following this link (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RQGIS/vignettes/install_guide.html#windows).

It works perfectly fine now along with GRASS and SAGA.